# Hide handles on Raphael JS Freetransform, but continue dragging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, transform, drag

Hi I am working on a new project which requires the use of Raphael JS and the plugin Raphael.Freetransform. So far the plugin is working extremely well and very smoothly. However, by using the hideHandles() method, it seems to also disable any form of dragging on an object.

Is this a bug or a design choice? Do I need to reenable dragging on an element once I hide its handles? I have tried to set up. Is there anything in particular which I need to do in order to make an element draggable without using the Freetransform plugin?

Here is my code:

```
paper = new Raphael("container", "1680", "1005");
setA = paper.set();
circle = paper.circle(50, 50, 50);
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
circle.attr("stroke", "#000");
notif = paper.circle(50, 50, 50);
notif.attr({ "fill": "r(0.5, 0.5) #fff-#f00", "fill-opacity": 1 });
lbl = paper.text(50, 50, "Label").attr({fill: '#000000'});
setA.push(circle);
setA.push(notif);
setA.push(lbl);

setA.click(function(){
    console.log('clicked');
});

setA.hover(
    // over //
    function (){ console.log('over'); }, 
    // out //
    function (){ console.log('out'); }
);

setA.drag(
    //onmove
    function(){  
        console.log('object moving');
    }, 
    //onstart
    function(){  
        console.log('start drag');
    }, 
    //onend
    function(){  
        console.log('end drag');
    }
);

ft = paper.freeTransform(setA, { drag: true, keepRatio: true, draw: [ 'bbox', 'circle' ] }, function(ft, events) { /*console.log(ft.attrs);*/ } );

$('#guideBtn').click(function(){
    if ($('#guideBtn').text().indexOf('Show') > -1){ ft.showHandles(); $('#guideBtn').text('Hide Guide'); }
    else{ ft.hideHandles(); $('#guideBtn').text('Show Guide'); }
});
```

and here is a link to the freetransform tool: https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform/

As you can see, I am just using a button's click handler to show and hide the handles. Do I need an extra step following this?

Thanks in advance,
Conor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured this out. Rather than calling .hideHandles() and .showHandles() you can simply call a combination of {drag: true|false}, {scale: true|false} and {rotate: true|false}

For example

```
circle.setOpts({drag:'self', scale:false, rotate:false, draw:false});
circle.setOpts({drag:'self', scale:true, rotate:true, draw: [ 'bbox', 'circle' ]});
```